# Why in screen video recorded with kazam I can not hear how other people speek?

Tags: kde, kazam

I record video when I use google meet with kazam under kubuntu 20 and watching recorded video
I hear my own voice ok, but I hardly hear how other people speek - voice is very low
and some noise in the background....

During google meet I hear how other people speek qiute good, the problem is only on recorder video...

How that can be fixed?

Which options of kazam / OS can be fixed ?

```
kazam Version: 1.4.5-3ubuntu0.1

$ uname -a
Linux master-at-home 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 13:27:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're capturing the sound from microphone but not the sound from speakers

enable **Sound from speakers** and it will record your friends as well
[image]

you may need to check which speaker is being recorded as well, go to the settings and check whether it's recording your headset's speakers or internal speakers, if you're using an earphone then **Playback Devices** should be set to **Headphones**

[image]

Comment: Starting new kazam session I have all options on : https://prnt.sc/c0GR8vBv5xwL  .Btw it is  MSI GP70-2PE (GP702PE-426XUA)  laptop. Can be some OS options ?

Comment: check your output device in your settings, maybe it's set to your internal speaker and kazam is recording the headset or vice versa